# Assembly code explanation

Tags: debugging, assembly, masm, cpu-registers

I stumbled upon a problem that I cannot fix nor can I find a solution in the web.
I've got a simple code fragment in MASM

```
abc dw 254, 255, 256
(...)
mov eax, dword PTR abc + 1
```

When I debug this code, after doing to second line, my eax register shows 0000FF00 and I have no idea why. 
I know that dword ptr means the number should be treated as a 32bit number and I have defined a the 16bit sequences. Could anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I debug this code, after doing to second line, my eax register shows 0000FF00

The code is loading a `DWORD` (4 bytes) into `EAX` from the address starting at `abc + 1`.

Let's write out the array contents in hex:

```
00FEh, 00FFh, 0100h
```

Or, expressed as bytes:

```
0FEh, 00h, 0FFh, 00h, 00h, 01h
```

So you get the `DWORD` formed by `00h, 0FFh, 00h, 00h`, which when interpreted as a little-endian `DWORD` is `0000FF00h`.

Comment: Thank you! Seems like my problem was connected to little-endian notation :)